# Click Function issue. Toggle between two div's with same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to create a separate function that can be used to call the click element and show element directly without making it to create again and again by calling the function directly. So I just got stuck when click on the other second div the first div not getting hidden. So kindly help me with this. I tried this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    showNav(".clickElement",".dropElement");    
    showNav(".AnotherElement",".AnotherDropElement");    
    showNav(".thirdElement",".thirdDropElement");    
});

function showNav(clickElement,showElement)
{
    jQuery(showElement).removeClass("dropdownElement");
    jQuery(showElement).hide();
    jQuery(clickElement).each(function(){
        jQuery(this).click(function(e){
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
            jQuery(showElement).toggle();
            jQuery(showElement).toggleClass("dropdownElement");
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        jQuery(document).on("click",".dropdownElement",function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        jQuery(document).click(function(e) {
            if(jQuery(e.target).hasClass(clickElement)||jQuery(e.target).hasClass(showElement))
            {
                console.log(clickElement);
            }
            else
            {   console.log(clickElement);      
                jQuery(clickElement).removeClass("active");         
                jQuery(document).find(".dropdownElement").hide();
                jQuery(document).find(".dropdownElement").removeClass("dropdownElement");
            }
        }); 

    });
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="clickElement">Click Function</div>
        <div class="dropElement" style="display: none">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="AnotherElement">Click Function</div>
        <div class="AnotherDropElement" style="display: none">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="thirdElement">Click Function</div>
        <div class="thirdDropElement" style="display: none">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul li { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;    
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Example Snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/w6csxcgk/)

Answer (score 2):

you do not need these many functions, just a simple `click event` is needed

As far as `HTML` is concerned you just have to add the class `showDiv` instead of three separate classes like `dropElement,AnotherDropElement,thirdDropElement`

This will also hide the `divs` if you click outside the `target`

```
$('.showDiv').hide();
$(function(){

    $('ul li').click(function(){
        var thisDiv = $(this).find('.showDiv');
        thisDiv.show();
        $('ul li').find('.showDiv').not(thisDiv).hide();
    });
    $(document).click(function(){
        if(event.target.nodeName == 'HTML'){
          $('ul li').find('.showDiv').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Check out the **[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/w6csxcgk/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you with your issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/18yao91v/254/

```
$("#img1").on('click', function() {
   $("#div1").fadeIn();
   $("#div2,#div3,#div4").fadeOut();
});
$("#img2").on('click', function() {
   $("#div2").fadeIn();
   $("#div1,#div3,#div4").fadeOut();
});
$("#img3").on('click', function() {
   $("#div3").fadeIn();
   $("#div1,#div2,#div4").fadeOut();
});
$("#img4").on('click', function() {
   $("#div4").fadeIn();
   $("#div1,#div2,#div3").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But i dont want to be static. I wanted to be automatically done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use easily within two jquery steps with same HTML, you mentioned above

Here is the Jquery code

```
$('ul li div:first-child').click(function() {
    $('ul li div:first-child').next('div').hide();
    $(this).next('div').show();
});
```

jsfiddle:

1. [link1](http://jsfiddle.net/w6csxcgk/9/) - (without body event bubbling)
2. [link2](http://jsfiddle.net/w6csxcgk/12/) - (with body event
   bubbling)

Comment: Is there any way that i ca use it as a function because the click element and show element will not be inside the li alone